# Cadmium Poisoning and Toxicity Mechanisms

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, toxicology

Is anyone aware of the toxic mechanisms of specific instances in which cadmium ions can interfere with cellular functions resulting in acute cadmium poisoning?

Comment: What have you found in your own attempts to research the question?